# Lightning Components: can aura:id be set to an component attribute?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I know it was never possible in Visualforce, but I wonder if it might be possible now in Lightning Components to have an aura:id not hardcoded but bound on an element like:

```
 <div aura:id="{!v.whatever}" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The alternative to this is to dynamically create the component using $A.createComponent and since attribute is accessible via the JavaScript one can assign dynamic values to aura:I'd

Currently the expression syntax is not supported in the aura:id attribute

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not possible to dynamically set `aura:id` based on `aura:attribute` for any component, it should always point to literal/hardcoded string value.

Below statement is mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm).

> aura:id doesn't support expressions. You can only assign literal
>   string values to aura:id.

Having aura:id point to Aura Expression, will not throw error when saving the markup.

```
<div aura:id="{!v.whatever}" /> //No error
```

But when trying find the div using `component.find()` , you won't be able to locate the div(i.e aura:html) it will return `undefined`.

```
component.find(cmp.get("v.whatever")) // returns undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic ids you may use

```
 <div id="{!v.whatever}" />
```

Then, in your controller you'll have to use `document.getElementById` instead of `cmp.find()`.

Comment: Yes, it maybe works but its anti-pattern in lightning.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible to save an component having markup like

```
<div aura:id="v.whatever" />
```

however an usage like this in the controller

```
cmp.find( cmp.get("v.whatever") )
```

will come back empty. So my assumption is, that it is not possible by design - even if the markup parser does not complain about it.

Answer (score 1):

Its a known limitation of Lightning components and the work around is to create dynamic components from client side helper and set the id there