# Setting of value to <ui:inputText ,based on aura:id

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration, inputtext, aura-id, js-controller

I want to set the value based on key,using aura:id

Component:

### {!mapKey.key}

```
                                            <label class="slds-checkbox slds-box" style="width:100%;">
                                                <ui:inputCheckbox text="{!mapValue}"
                                                                  value="{!mapValue.isChecked}"
                                                                  aura:id="{!index}"

                                                                  change="{!c.selectSubProcess}"/>
                                                <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" /> &nbsp;
                                                <span class="slds-form-element__label" style="font-size: 15px;">{!mapValue.subprocessName}</span>
                                                <br/> </label>
                                            <aura:if isTrue="{!mapValue.isChecked}">
                                                <!-- tt<lightning:input name="input2" label="we" value="{!v.O2CWeightage}" class="field"/>-->

                                                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                                                    <span  class="slds-col">

                                                        <ui:inputText aura:id="{!mapValue.key}" label="Weightage:" 
                                                                      class="field"
                                                                      labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                                                      value="{!mapValue.Weightage}"
                                                                      required="false"/>
                                                 <aura:iteration items="{!v.SubProcessMap}" var="cus" indexVar="key">

                                                     <aura:if isTrue="{!cus.key==mapValue.key}">
                                                      {!cus.value}
                                                     </aura:if>
                                                        </aura:iteration>
                                                    </span><span  class="slds-col">
                                                    <img src="{!$Resource.Edit_Icon}" onclick="{!c.editO2C}"/>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </aura:if>


                                        </aura:iteration>
```

Controller.js:

```
for(var key in countStrings){
            console.log(key);
            SubProcessMap.push({key: key, value: 100/countStrings[key]});  
        }
        component.set("v.SubProcessMap",SubProcessMap);
        console.log('SubProcessMap==>'+JSON.stringify(SubProcessMap));
        //Setting of Value
        var weightage=[];
        weightage= component.find("selectedprocesskeys.key");
```

My map values are:

SubProcessMap==>[{"key":"Vendor Master","value":25},{"key":"Customer Master","value":50}]

ANd,now in component i want to set aura:id as {!mapValue.key},bcoz it should key as Vendor Master,customer master......

and based on key,value should be kept in input box

Answer (score 1):

In lightning component, **you cannot assign aura ID a dynamic value.**
Check this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154416/lightning-components-can-auraid-be-set-to-an-component-attribute) for more information.

You can **leverage *HTML Data attributes*** in iteration to keep dynamic IDs or Keys for identification of particular data in the controller using the event from where the element was triggered.

**Aura Component Snippet**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.SearchResults}" var="sr"  indexvar="index">
    <tr onclick="{!c.selected}" data-record="{!sr.Id}">   
    <td><ui:outputText value="{!sr.Id}"/></td>
```

**Controller Snippet**

```
selected: function(cmp,event,helper){
   var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
   var recId = selectedItem.dataset.record;
```